# How Do I use libbsm/openbsm with Swift5 on macOS?

Tags: macos, swift5

I try to use libbsm/openbsm library and Swift5 in Xcode11.
Why? I can not fine `AUDITPIPE_SET_PRESELECT_MODE`.
Can I use libbsm/openbsm in Swift?

```
var mode = AUDITPIPE_PRESELECT_MODE_LOCAL // <- works very well
if ioctl(auditFD, AUDITPIPE_SET_PRESELECT_MODE, &mode) == -1 {
    return -1
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into the same issue with Swift unable to import these complex macros.  Quinn “The Eskimo!” pointed me in the direction of declaring them as c constants. So I created them in a c file in my project.

In the .h file I did the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <bsm/libbsm.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <security/audit/audit_ioctl.h>


// -- Macros used for creating an auditpipe
extern unsigned long QAUDITPIPE_SET_PRESELECT_MODE;
extern unsigned long QAUDITPIPE_GET_QLIMIT_MAX;
extern unsigned long QAUDITPIPE_SET_QLIMIT;
extern unsigned long QAUDITPIPE_SET_PRESELECT_FLAGS;
extern unsigned long QAUDITPIPE_SET_PRESELECT_NAFLAGS;
// -- End auditpipe macros
```

And in my .c file i have:

```
unsigned long QAUDITPIPE_SET_PRESELECT_MODE = AUDITPIPE_SET_PRESELECT_MODE;
unsigned long QAUDITPIPE_GET_QLIMIT_MAX = AUDITPIPE_GET_QLIMIT_MAX;
unsigned long QAUDITPIPE_SET_QLIMIT = AUDITPIPE_SET_QLIMIT;
unsigned long QAUDITPIPE_SET_PRESELECT_FLAGS = AUDITPIPE_SET_PRESELECT_FLAGS;
unsigned long QAUDITPIPE_SET_PRESELECT_NAFLAGS = AUDITPIPE_SET_PRESELECT_NAFLAGS;
```

So now I can just use QAUDITPIPE_SET_PRESELECT_MODE in my Swift code.  Works great!